# Javascript callback returning results

Tags: javascript, callback, return

How can I get `results` returned to `placesSearch` function, rather than returning `results` to `service.nearbySearch` function? Thanks

```
function placesSearch(map,myLatlng,myBusinessName) {

        var searchArea = myLatlng;

        var request = {
            location: searchArea,
            radius: 500
        };

        var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

        var googleBusNames = service.nearbySearch(request, callback);

        validateFeature(googleBusNames,myBusinessName);
    }

    function callback(results, status) {

        if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            return results;
        }
        else {
            console.log("Error");
        }        
    }
```

Comment: You can't. That's why the function accepts a callback in the first place.

Comment: I think the closure was a bit hasty. A long community wiki is going to take a lot longer to process if the user is confused about callbacks than a relevant answer to this question.